# How to Work with 'Environment Variables' with Java Servlet Web Application

Tags: java, tomcat

To set the scene...

1x Apache Tomcat instance
Hosting multiple Web Applications
For each, a Web App X Dev, Web App X Test, Web App X Live to handle the SDLC.

Hence I put Environment Variables in quotes as I'm not talking about Linux layer Environment Variables as this wouldn't work, just more the web application layer config settings.

The goal is to get config settings out of the codebase and managed on the server, specifically within the application files.

I've managed to get the right file path at the Servlet layer with the command;

```
request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

But most config settings sit outside the HttpServletRequest object so I don't want to go passing this down through the codebase layers as that would be a nightmare.

I guess, what I'm essentially looking for, I think, is the equivalent of "Get me the document root of the web app X that sits on Tomcat"

I've searched around on this topic for a while and I've not managed to find a working example.

Comment: Please explain where you are storing the configuration settings

Comment: [*Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) my be useful.

Comment: @tgdavies At the minute just in the codebase, but this doesn't work when you need to implement CI/CD pipelines etc. So looking to get the config outside the codebase. Seems to be possible when only hosting 1x application on Tomcat, but not found a way when hosting multiple applications on the same Tomcat instance.